# Krazy Glue Color Change

Tags: everyday-chemistry, color

A type of Krazy Glue changes from purple to clear when it dries. What is the chemistry behind the color change? Is it due to a particular compound only found in this particular Glue?

[A description of glue can be found on their website.](http://www.krazyglue.com/product/details/krazy-glue-color-change#.WT3qezopBxA)